# Программы отладчики

Tags: отладка

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла проблем с написанием исследовательской работы по теме "Сравнение программ отладчиков OllyDbg, Softice, TurboDebugger и DDD". Времени в данный момент заниматься подобным у меня нет, опыт программирования совсем небольшой. Информации в сети на эту тему тоже мизер. О опытнейшие, помогите сравнить данные отладчики, описать какие использовали и при разработке каких программ. Чем отличаются и т.д. Буду рад любому развернутому ответу.

Comment: отладчик:
под какой осью работает?актуален ли на данный момент?
работает на 3 или 0 м кольце?
позволяет отлаживать код удаленно?
позволяет использовать скриптовые языки, плагины для упрощения процесса отладки?
посмотри в интернете что должен уметь хороший отладчик и на базе этой инфы выполни сравнение. все равно тебе больше текста нужно, больше чем ответ на форуме.

Comment: В вики (про 3 написано) не читали?

Думаете будут желающие написать подробнее?

Comment: @vv2cc ну так обзор отладчиков у меня есть. Мне необходимо их сравнение, какой где используется иначе мне сказали что это не исследовательская. + Вообще информации мизер. Типа нужно от себя добавить мнение, но я ни один пока из них не пользовал и думаю софтайс буду использовать еще не скоро.

Comment: @avp вики - не источник. (мне его использовать нельзя) + то что там написано не есть исследование.

Comment: разработку Softice закрыли давно уже. WinDbg разве что из замены ему под Windows... Syser тоже, но очень часто падал у меня на компе. это отладчики позволяющие работать с Ring0 кодом. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
Во-первых сразу хочется сказать, что **SoftIce** мертв (если конечно вы не собираетесь использовать в своей работе **winXP SP1** и это как максимум).
**OllyDebuger** - замечательный отладчик **ring3** (драйвера и ядрышки им отлаживать имхо нельзя (хотя никогда не говори никогда )) )) Рекомендую начать с него. Есть и справка на русском, как-то переводили и выкладывали на http://www.cracklab.ru
**TurboDebugger** - тоже старая вещь
Аналог **SoftIce** - **Syser Kernel Debuger**, от китайских разработчиков, правда я не помню, похоже полнофункциональная версия платная. Мощный отладчик
Также от мелкомягких их собственный отладчик - **Win DBG** (им можно отлаживать ядро системы, Win естественно).
Еще есть **Immunity Debuger** - некий аналог **Olly DBG**, но все же рекомендую Ольку.
В общем порекомендовать для ваших исследований могу следующую тройку:
**Olly DBG** для отладки в **RING-3**
**Syser DBG** - для отладки драйверов и системного барахла
**Win DBG** - для отладки в **RING-0**

Comment: В IDA есть еще встроенный отладчик, его тоже часто используют ;)

Comment: @vv2cc IDA Pro - вообще суперская вещь.
Помню в далеком прошлом был пакет Driver Studio - включал все необходимое для отладки - ресерчинга, классная штука была.
Имхо лучше использовать связку IDA + Olly

Comment: > Immunity Debuger - некий аналог Olly DBG
Скорее, "некая модификация" OllyDbg.

Comment: можно и так сказать ))

Answer (score 0):

[@LaKO](/users/6442/lako), заинтересовали. Скачал DDD

```
sudo apt-get install ddd
```

(у меня xubuntu 12.04). Попробовал C.

Сходу вызвало недоумение, что русский язык в исходнике (UTF-8) не показывает. Т.е. Emacs показывает, терминал показывает, а `ddd` нет.

А так - простой иксовый графический интерфейс к gdb с менюшками (в т.ч. контекстными по правой кнопке мыша). На первый взгляд (если отвлечься от русского языка) вроде неплохо, но изменение размера окна отрисовывает как-то (на мой вкус) дергано.

Попробовал отладку sh, python и т.д. - требует установки соответствующих отладчиков.
С собой ничего не несет.

---

Вообще я стараюсь не пользоваться отладчиком. Опыт показывает, что часто быстрее получаешь результат, если попечатать переменные в нужных местах и подумать.